# Docker for windows - File shares

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, windows-container

I want to mount a file share in a windows container.
I have tried to mount an Azure File storage share, and intially it works fine. I can browse the files in the directory.

However, when I disconnect and reconnect my container powershell-session, the share is marked 'Unavailable'.
Also, the share is not available to the executable running as my ENTRYPOINT.

```
    docker exec -it a4 powershell
    **************
    PS C:\> net use z: \\XXXX.file.core.windows.net\dockerstore /u:XXXXX XXXXXX== /P:Yes
    The command completed successfully.

    PS C:\> net use
    New connections will be remembered.


    Status       Local     Remote                    Network

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OK           Z:        \\XXXX.file.core.windows.net\dockerstore
                                                    Microsoft Windows Network
    The command completed successfully.


    exit

    ******************
    docker exec -it a4 powershell
    **********************
    PS C:\> net use
    New connections will be remembered.


    Status       Local     Remote                    Network

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Unavailable  Z:        \\XXXX.file.core.windows.net\dockerstore
                                                    Microsoft Windows Network
    The command completed successfully.
```

I also tried mounting the network drive on the host, and mounting it in the container.
But docker-compose fails to bring it up (access-problem?):

```
Cannot create container for service configserver-c: invalid bind mount spec "z:\\Certificates:c:\\Certificates:rw": invalid volume specification: 'z:\Certificates:c:\Certificates:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist
```

Are there other options to persistently mount an external file share?
(I don't know of any Docker Volume drivers available for windows.)

Some more information:
I use Docker for Windows on Windows 10 with Hyper-V isolation.

Docker version:

```
    Client:
     Version:      17.03.1-ce
     API version:  1.27
     Go version:   go1.7.5
     Git commit:   c6d412e
     Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
     OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

    Server:
     Version:      17.03.1-ce
     API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
     Go version:   go1.7.5
     Git commit:   c6d412e
     Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
     OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
     Experimental: true
```

Comment: Shares exist only in user session which you created, other users or other session will not see it. It works the same way on you desktop. Try to use $session object instead `PS C:\> $session = New-PSSession -ContainerId (get-Container ed).ID -RunAsAdministrator

PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {$env:mytest = "test"}

PS C:\> Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {Write-Output $env:mytest}

test`

Comment: @GSA Thanks for your input. Think I will try to use CMDKEY to add credentials to the user, and use UNC paths instead. Will post the result.

Comment: What is your business with containers and necessity to have users login to container on console?

Comment: I have multiple services as containers. Both Windows-services and web-services. Some of these need access to files on an Azure Files storage. In the question above, I tried to put it simple. I do not need to do this using a console-session, it could be done in a script or in a Dockerfile. The main thing is that the user under which the service runs have access to the external storage.

Comment: @AndreasLudviksen Trying to do the exact same thing, did you get it working?

Comment: @eselk Yes. I was able to make the volume permanently available by using 'cmdkey' in the Dockerfile, and UNC paths in the application. Also, if I run the application under a user with the same username/password as the Azure File Storage, the application can access the storage. See this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488399/windows-container-fails-to-reach-azure-file-storage

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to mount volume when you build your images in the docker file.